# Monitoring Task completion

Tags: c#, task

I run several tasks and keep them in a list to check if they are already completed.

I discovered that tasks that come from an `async` method are always shown as `RanToCompletion` although the task itself was still running.

Is there a way to get the "is complete" information from a `Task` object in both cases?

Here's a simple test case that shows this behaviour. I run two tasks, with/without an `async` method and check the states during and after completion.

```
private void test()
{

    ;
    Action actionAsync = funcAsync;
    Task taskAsync = Task.Run(actionAsync);
    Action action = func;
    Task task = Task.Run(action);

    var statusAsync = taskAsync.Status;
    var status = task.Status;

    // stati are either WaitingToRun or Running

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

    // Now it's quite certain, that both have started

    var statusAsync2 = taskAsync.Status;
    var status2 = task.Status;

    Debug.Assert(statusAsync2 == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);
    Debug.Assert(status2 == TaskStatus.Running);

    ;

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12));

    // Now it's quite certain, that both have finished

    var statusAsync3 = taskAsync.Status;
    var status3 = task.Status;
    ;

    Debug.Assert(statusAsync3 == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);
    Debug.Assert(status3 == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);

}



private async void funcAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
}
private  void func()
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I discovered that tasks that come from an async method are always shown as RanToCompletion although the task itself was still running.

Yes, because your `void` method has completed, and that's all that `Task.Run` is calling. If instead you use:

```
private async Task FuncAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
}
```

and use `Func<Task>` instead `Action`, then you'll call [`Task.Run(Func<Task>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160382(v=vs.110).aspx) and all will be well.

Short but complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<Task> func = FuncAsync;
        Task task = Task.Run(func);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(task.Status);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }        
    }

    private static async Task FuncAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
WaitingForActivation
WaitingForActivation
WaitingForActivation
WaitingForActivation
WaitingForActivation
RanToCompletion
RanToCompletion
```

Try to avoid writing `void` async methods if you possibly can. They should basically only be used for event handlers.